# Serialize the response as nested field in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I had been trying to make a nested json instead of flat json. What I am getting is,

```
{
    "field1": "value1",
    "field2": "value2" 
}
```

And I am trying to make as,

```
{
    "field1": "value1",
    "extra": {
        "x1" : "value2",
        "comment": "my comment"
    }
}
```

My model is simple,

```
class MyModel(BaseMeta):
    field1 = models.CharField(db_column='field1', primary_key=True, max_length=11)
    field2 = models.CharField(db_column='field2')
```

Serializer is

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['field1', 'field2']
```

The solution is the following,

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    extra = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_extra')
    class Meta:
        model = CowMating
        fields = ['field1', 'extra']

    def get_extra(self, obj):
        return {
            'x1': obj.field2,
            'comment': 'my comments'
        }
```

But I am wondering if its possible to write another serializer like,

```
class ExtraSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    x1 = serializers.CharField(source='field2')
    comment = "my comment"
```

and the serializer would be in the `ModelSerializer`,

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    extra = ExtraSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['field1', 'extra ']
```

Please give some advice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What would be the benefit of having `ExtraSerializer` where you can simply achieve what you want through `SerializerMethodField` :) ?

Comment: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#using-source

Comment: And There is an extra space. fields = ['field1', 'extra '] => fields = ['field1', 'extra']

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible that you can refer another serializer in another for nested data and also there's  django **[property](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/glossary/#glossary)** that you can use.

**your way**

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    extra = ExtraSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['field1', 'extra ']
        depth = 1 .    #<--- Add this
```

**Property**

`models.py`

Suppose you have two models `MyModel1` and `MyModel2` which has Foreignkey relationship with the `MyModel1`.

```
class MyModel1(BaseMeta):
    field1 = models.CharField(db_column='field1', primary_key=True, max_length=11)
    field2 = models.CharField(db_column='field2')
    @property
    def mymodel2_prop(self, obj):
        from appname.serializer import MyModel2Serialzers    #you have to implement a simple serializer fro MyModel2 which is imported here.
        return MyModel2Serilzers(mymodel2_set.all()).data
```

So you import the serializer which is optional but a good practice to validate data. using reverse relationship you use `set` to get the related data in `MyModel1` API

```
class MyModel2(BaseMeta):
        some_field1 = models.ForeignKey(MyModel1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

`serializers.py`

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['field1', 'mymodel2_prop ']
```

**This is to give you an idea, Code is untested**

Comment: I tried putting @property def extra(self): return {}. it does not work. Could you please tell me more?

Comment: Thanks @ans2human, the problem is that I do not have two models and no database relation. I just want to add an extra field in the nested json.

Comment: Property is not dependent on relation, you can add any data using property. Otherwise your way which i have summarized is the way to go.